# Need a wordpress plugin for Google analytics, favicon!

Tags: wordpress, plugins, metadata, favicon

I am using wordpress for my site. My site needs to add google analytics, favicon, meta keywords, meta descriptions. I searched plugin for this. I found different plugins for each. Can anyone suggest me a plugin which can add google analytis, favicon, metakeywords and meta description?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not programming related and should be asked on the wordpress stackexchange site http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

These are different functionalities and are properly handled by different plugins.  Install the plugins you need.  On Linux platforms, you can often just put the favicon in the sites root directory and not use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the keywords and description meta tags are ignored by all search engines because spammers exploit the heck out of them. I suggest not bothering with them. However, if you still want to, read [what the WordPress guys say](http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress).

As for Google Analytics and favicons, here are the plugins I recommend:

- [Shockingly Simple Favicon](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shockingly-simple-favicon/)
- [Google Analytics for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)
- [Google Analytics Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard/) (Optional, but very useful. Shows an Analytics summary in your WordPress dashboard to save you time.)

Don't forget to also add a favicon.ico to your site root (even an empty one will do) to stop browsers from repeatedly attempting to retrieve it. (Don't believe me? Install any WordPress favicon plugin and then check your server logs.)

The `favicon.ico` in the site root will appear temporarily until the page has loaded enough for the `<head>` to be parsed and the new icon loaded, so I suggest not leaving it empty. Some sites (eg. deviantART) even take advantage of that to display different icons for "loading" and "loaded".